# igraph get edge from - to value

Tags: r, igraph

I have an igraph graph and want to simply get each edge's `from_id` and `to_id`. For example:

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(4, 1, type="gnm", directed=FALSE)
E(g)[1] # will return some edge, possibly not the same one
# Edge sequence:
# e       
# e [1] 3 -- 1
```

What I want is to get two variables `v1`, `v2` where `v1 = 3` and `v2 = 1` (equivalent to `v1 = 1` and `v2 = 3`). I want to do this for all edges in the graph `E(g)[x], where x is the loop variable`. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`get.edges()` returns all edges, `get.edge()` returns one edge. If you need to iterate over all edges, then call `get.edges()` and go over all lines of the two-column matrix, with `apply()`, or a for loop.

Answer (score 7):

`get.edgelist(g)` is the one you want, which spits out a matrix like:

```
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    1
```

Answer (score 1):

If g is you igraph then try  `ends(g,es = E(g))`